# Cómo comparar el valor de un campo de una tabla con el valor de un input radio en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Estoy creando una pequeña app donde habrá unas preguntas tipo test y cada una tendrá 4 opciones (inputs radio) y quiero validarlas, o sea, cuando le doy al botón de validar la pregunta, que me diga si es correcta o no. El caso es que intento comparar el campo de respuesta correcta, que no aparece en formulario, pero sí está en la tabla, con el valor del input radio seleccionado. Pero solo me valida bien la primera pregunta, la segunda sigue cogiendo el valor de la respuesta correcta de la primera pregunta. Soy nuevo con Laravel y no sé bien cómo solucionarlo. ¿Alguien podría echarme una mano? ¡Muchas gracias!

Añado código: Código de la función que valida, está dentro de un controlador:

```
public function validar(Request $request)
    {
        $examenes = Prueba::all();               
        $opcion = $request->input('optradio');         
        

        foreach($examenes as $examen){
            if($opcion == $examen->correcta){                
                dd($examen->correcta);               
               /*return back()->withSuccess(['Respuesta correcta']);*/              
            }
            else{               
                dd($examen->correcta);
                /*return back()->withDanger(['Respuesta incorrecta']);*/
            }        
           
        }
    }
```

Código de la vista, del formulario donde salen las preguntas con las opciones de respuesta, cuando la persona selecciona un input de esa pregunta, quiero que se compare con la respuesta correcta de esa pregunta, que solo aparece en la tabla de la base de datos.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Preguntas</h2>
        @foreach ($examenes as $examen)
        
            <p>{{ $examen->pregunta }}</p>


            <form action="{{ route('validar') }}" method="POST" >
                @csrf
                <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1" name="optradio" value="{{ $examen->opcion_1 }}">{{ $examen->opcion_1 }}
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2" name="optradio" value="{{ $examen->opcion_2 }}">{{ $examen->opcion_2 }}
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="radio3">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio3" name="optradio" value="{{ $examen->opcion_3 }}">{{ $examen->opcion_3 }}
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="radio4">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio4" name="optradio" value="{{ $examen->opcion_4 }}">{{ $examen->opcion_4 }}
                    </label>
                  </div>                 
                  
            @endforeach
            <input type="submit" id="valida" class="btn btn-success" value="Validar">                  
          </form> 

            {{ $examenes->links() }}   
              
            <div>     

              @if (session()->has('success'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    @if(is_array(session()->get('success')))
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                        @foreach (session()->get('success') as $message)
                            <li>{{ $message }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>              
                        
                    @endif
                </div> 
              @endif
              @if (session()->has('danger'))
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                @if(is_array(session()->get('danger')))
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                    @foreach (session()->get('danger') as $message)
                        <li>{{ $message }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>              
                @endif
              </div>
              @endif
            </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo he solucionado, pero no estoy seguro si es la mejor opción. He creado un input tipo hidden en el formulario, con el valor de la respuesta correcta

```
<input type="hidden" name="optcorrecta" value="{{ $examen->correcta }}" />
```

y luego en el controlador creo una variable para ello y lo comparo en el if, sin el foreach.

```
public function validar(Request $request)
    {
        
        $respuesta = $request->input('optcorrecta');
        $opcion = $request->input('optradio'); 
        if($opcion == $respuesta){                
            return back()->withSuccess(['Respuesta correcta']);                           
        }
        else{
            return back()->withDanger(['Respuesta incorrecta']);
        }    
    }
```

Y de esta manera por fin me funciona!!! Sólo no sé si es una manera adecuada, ¿me podéis confirmarlo? ¡Muchas gracias!

PD: Me he dado cuenta que, como es obvio, si inspeccionamos la página, el input hidden sale y enseña la respuesta correcta. Así que no creo que sea la mejor opción. Si alguien sabe cómo hacerlo mejor, por favor, que me lo diga, gracias!